# Why does Aikuro Mikisugi request everyone to use the DTR acronym?

Tags: kill-la-kill

In the anime "Kill la Kill", Aikuro Mikisugi hates and avoids the expression "Dōtonbori robo" and requests everyone using that phrase to say "DTR" instead. Does this phrase have some hidden meaning that explains his behavior, or is it explained otherwise in canon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dotonbori is a street within the redlight district of Osaka that sees the highest number of prostitutes working on it. He is probably embarrassed or doesn't want DTR to be associated with Dotonbori, considering their (DTR) preference to be nude could be taken the wrong way by the average person.